# How to pass parameters through to different AWS SAM files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I seperated my SAM stack into multiple files like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── lambda_template.yaml
.
.
.
└── template.yaml
```

So that I could have different lambdas (and their associated resources) in different files.

My main `template.yaml` file looks something like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template

Resources:

  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      # Lambda function
      Location: ./lambda_template.yaml
```

Then within `./lambda_template.yaml` I have the actual definition of the lambda:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sam Template deploys MyLambda.

Parameters:
    Environment:
      Description: 'Required. Environment you are deploying to -- not working'
      Type: String
      Default: 'develop'
Resources:
# Details about the input_object_processor Lambda function
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      ...
```

I want to be able to make a parameter, then override it on the command line during `sam deploy ....`

I thought that you can do the following:
`sam deploy ... --parameter-overrides Environment=QA`
but that didnt work so I tried:

`sam deploy ... --parameter-overrides ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=-qa`

But it doesn't seem to respect the update, and just uses the default. Is there a way to make SAM pass the parameter through to the sub-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been working on this off and on for a while, and have finally figured it out. It's a little embarrassing that it took me so long to try the solution that seems to have worked. Hopefully this can save someone else some time in the future:

My main template.yaml file now looks something like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: 'Required. Environment you are deploying to'
    Type: String

Resources:

  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
      Location: ./lambda_template.yaml
```

and my `./lambda_template.yaml` file now looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sam Template deploys MyLambda.

Parameters:
    Environment:
      Description: 'Required. Environment you are deploying to -- not working'
      Type: String
      
Resources:
# Details about the input_object_processor Lambda function
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::Join:
          - "-"
          - - "my"
            - Ref: Environment
            - 'lambda'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sam deploy does look correct

have you tried encompassing your parameter overrides in double quotes

```
sam deploy ... --parameter-overrides "ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=qa"
```

Comment: Ok, figured it out, you do not need to have it in quotes